# couldn't connect to database using mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to work on my ajax.php for my chat application but for some reason I could not connect to my database. I don't get why I get this error message

> Notice: Undefined variable: dbOptions on line 21
>
> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DB::init() must be of the type array, null given, called on line 21 and defined on line 20

Here's my code

**ajax.php**

```
<?php
require "classes/DB.class.php";
require "classes/Chat.class.php";
require "classes/ChatBase.class.php";
require "classes/ChatLine.class.php";
require "classes/ChatUser.class.php";

session_name('webchat');
session_start();

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){

    // If magic quotes is enabled, strip the extra slashes
    array_walk_recursive($_GET,create_function('&$v,$k','$v = stripslashes($v);'));
    array_walk_recursive($_POST,create_function('&$v,$k','$v = stripslashes($v);'));
}

try{

    // Connecting to the database
    DB::init($dbOptions);

    $response = array();

    // Handling the supported actions:

    switch($_GET['action']){

        case 'login':
            $response = Chat::login($_POST['name'],$_POST['email']);
        break;

        case 'checkLogged':
            $response = Chat::checkLogged();
        break;

        case 'logout':
            $response = Chat::logout();
        break;

        case 'submitChat':
            $response = Chat::submitChat($_POST['chatText']);
        break;

        case 'getUsers':
            $response = Chat::getUsers();
        break;

        case 'getChats':
            $response = Chat::getChats($_GET['lastID']);
        break;

        default:
            throw new Exception('Wrong action');
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
}
catch(Exception $e){
    die(json_encode(array('error' => $e->getMessage())));
}
?>
```

**DB.class.php**

```
<?php
class DB {
    private static $instance;
    private $MySQLi;

    private function __construct(array $dbOptions){

        $this->MySQLi = @ new mysqli(   $dbOptions['localhost'],
                                        $dbOptions['root'],
                                        $dbOptions[''],
                                        $dbOptions['webchat'] );

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            throw new Exception('Database error.');
        }

        $this->MySQLi->set_charset("utf8");
    }

    public static function init(array $dbOptions){
        if(self::$instance instanceof self){
            return false;
        }

        self::$instance = new self($dbOptions);
    }

    public static function getMySQLiObject(){
        return self::$instance->MySQLi;
    }

    public static function query($q){
        return self::$instance->MySQLi->query($q);
    }

    public static function esc($str){
        return self::$instance->MySQLi->real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($str));
    }
}
?>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `$dbOptions` hasn't been set/given a value. And this isn't `PDO`, it's `mysqli` library

Comment: As above, where do you create the `$dbOptions` array?

Comment: PDO is a specific php class for connecting to databases, as is mysqli, which is what your code appears to be using. The error is because you haven't defined the variable $dbOptions anywhere, so php gives you an error and the function you are calling which requires this variable to be an array also shows an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You've not set `$dbOptions` to have a value.
- Your array keys are very illogical. I've taken the liberty to rename them for you.

Add in `ajax.php`

```
$dbOptions = array();
$dbOptions['host'] = "localhost";
$dbOptions['user'] = "root";
$dbOptions['pass'] = "";
$dbOptions['database'] = "webchat";

// Connecting to the database
DB::init($dbOptions);
```

Then modify `DB.class.php`

```
private function __construct(array $dbOptions){

    $this->MySQLi = new mysqli($dbOptions['host'],
                                    $dbOptions['user'],
                                    $dbOptions['pass'],
                                    $dbOptions['database'] );

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        throw new Exception('Database error.');
    }

    $this->MySQLi->set_charset("utf8");
}
```

Also, never suppress errors on connecting to the database. Handle them within exception logic, and send back `HTTP STATUS 500` if it fails.